# Laravel - sync() method in Many-to-many relationship not updating model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

My view has a multiple select box for which allows a user to be assigned certain assets. Users are pulled from table `users`, assets are pulled from table `assets`.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="assets" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Assets </label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         {{Form::select('assets[]',$user->assets, $user->takenAssets, ['id'=>'assets','multiple','class'=>'select2 form-control'])}}
      </div>
</div>
```

In the select box above, `$user->assets` lists an array taken from the model `Asset::all('name','id')`, taken assets are simply `$user->assets->pluck('id')->toArray();`. These are done to populate the box and then list the selected ones.

There are five text fields below this multiple select box which allow a user to enter optional serial numbers, each text box as a name field called `serialnumber[]`

Now once the controller receives the request, the following code runs:

```
if(!collect($request->assets)->isEmpty())
{
   for($i = 0; $i<count($request->assets);$i++)
   {
      $user->assets()->sync([$i+1 => array('serialnumber'=>$request->serialnumber[$i])]);
   }

}
```

The `$i+1` happening in the for loop is because of the way the `id`s in the `assets` tables start with 1. 
It's not updating the `asset_user` table. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method sync takes as parameter an array of IDs to synchronize and will dettach all of the others. That mean if you sync your IDs one by one, the first ID will be dettached when you will sync the second, the second will be dettached by the third...

If $request->assets is an array of IDs, why do you not simply do something like :

```
if($request->has('assets')) {
    $user->assets()->sync($request->assets);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm unsure how to handle the pivot `serialnumber[]` array

Comment: You can also use `syncWithoutDetaching` instead of `sync`.